# Runtime Activity Theme Change Issue

Tags: android, xamarin, themes, oncreate

When I remove the activity theme from its directive ([activity(Theme =)]) and set it in activity's OnCreate overrided method before base.OnCreate I expect the result be same but it does not. When I run app, first I see Android default theme then SetTheme change theme. As far as I know the OnCreate implement before an Activity is created!

Answer (score 0):

Save theme state on sharedPreferences, then load it inside onCreate(). When user click change theme, you need to reload activity, by starting it again.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I want to change splash screen color at future run when user change theme inside of app. Problem is here when I SetTheme in OnCreate method of Activity it change theme but before that Activity runs with Android default theme then when SetTheme implemented theme changed.

Comment: Yes, you need to load the theme on every activity is onCreate() method to change all activity theme

Comment: I know I must do that but when app comes to run first default theme is shown then theme by SetTheme implements.

Comment: Like I say, save theme state on SharedPreferences, and if you want to change the theme, just change the value on sharedPreferences

Comment: It does not matter because to set theme I should read SharedPreferences string and use SetTheme("SharedPreferences Value"). Problem here when e.g I have blue theme after I set to green theme in Activity's OnCreate method at app running for a while time it shows blue theme then changes it (by SetTheme) to green theme.